# Best practice/standards-compliant way to get character code of pressed key

Tags: javascript, events

Now that e.keyCode is deprecated, what should I do if I need the character code of a key press?

```
 if (e.key.charCodeAt() === 97)
```

is this okay? Also, is there any difference between this and

```
if (e.key.charCodeAt(0) === 97)
```

Is this a bad way to handle this kind of thing?

Comment: MDN uses charCodeAt(0) , I would call them a reliable source .https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/charCodeAt

Comment: Why not `e.key === 'a'` ?

Comment: @Evert It was just a mental exercise to see how one would gather keycode data now that .keyCode is deprecated. I thought maybe there'd be a simple way. but I've now learned that there isn't really. Ofc, e.key === "a" is sufficient for most purposes.